# Woocommerce move update cart button

Tags: php, css

I want to move update cart button next to the check out button. Im using NDOxygenVersion: 3.8

```
            <div class="cart-buttons-hidden">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="Update Basket" />
                <input type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" name="proceed" value="Proceed to Checkout" />
```

Can someone help please
site url:www.besthandles.co.uk

Many thanks.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZeqT.png)

Comment: Can you show us the theme's source code where it prints this?

Comment: im quite new here if you can visit www.besthandles.co.uk  when you go to shopping basket you will see update cart button doesnt stay next to checkout button. Just want to put them together thats all actually. Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you pust an screenshot? On Firefox I see them right to each other.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say this is only happening with chrome and safari thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it's taking the same padding as the previous div, so you need to clear any floating element to avoid that, just add this rule and it will be fixed:

```
.cart-env .cart-main-buttons { 
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me exactly where to add thanks a lot for ur help.

Comment: just that code to the theme's CSS, if the theme supports custom CSS, just copy and paste that into the inputbox